# IOS Scroll is not working after updating the angular project from version 6 to version 8?

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, scroll, angular8

After updating my angular project from version 6 to version 8 the scroll feature is not working in any of the screen with the ios mobiles(except iphone SE,In Iphone SE the scroll feature is working). In all android mobiles the scroll feature is working.
What could be the issue any idea?

Below is my ng cli version

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 12.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.5
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.5
@angular/cdk                       8.2.0
@angular/cli                       8.3.5
@angular/material                  8.2.0
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.2.0
@angular/pwa                       0.803.5
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.5
@schematics/angular                8.3.5
@schematics/update                 0.803.5
rxjs                               6.4.0
typescript                         3.5.3
webpack                            4.39.2
```

Comment: Hi Jagadeesh.

Sorry my english is very poor.

The first step backup your project.
But i have the same problem, but it´s possible that you use  the library hammer.js, if this your case can you show your version.

you change the version hammer downgrade or upgrade, until it´s works.

Comment: You were right actually. It works after downgrading the hammer.js version from version
2.0.8 to version
2.0.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..! By downgrading the hammer.js version from version 2.0.8 to version 2.0.6.